# Use ImageMagick with python. (on a linux system)

Tags: python, linux, imagemagick

I want to define a function that "call" imagemagick to convert an image.

```
def convert(filein,fileout):
#imagemagick>convert filein fileout
```

How can I call and use imagemagick with Python?

I'm running on a linux system, imagemagick is installed, and I'm not using PIL.module because it doesn't handle PPM[p3].

Comment: give Wand a try, http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.1/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either use one of the shell interfaces of Python (os.system, subprocess.Popen) to call the imagemagick binary, or try out [PythonMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/python/).

Comment: thanks , os.system works perferctly.

Answer (score 15):

**Disclaimer**: I am the author of Wand.

You can easily do that using [Wand](http://wand-py.org/), a simple binding of ImageMagick for Python.  For example, the following code converts a PNG image to a JPEG image:

```
from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename='in.png') as img:
    img.format = 'jpeg'
    img.save(filename='out.jpg')
```

See [this tutorial](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.3.4/guide/write.html#save-to-file) as well.

Comment: Can you resize it to 300% , how do you add the flatten , and how do you change the background ?

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest u use **subprocess** it is safer

```
import subprocess
params = ['convert', 'src_file', 'result_file']
subprocess.check_call(params)
```

Comment: Good answer, also has the benefit that you don't need to load it into memory if it's already on disk

Answer (score 3):

I have not used image magic but you could use os.system to call a shell command:

```
import os
os.system('imagemagick-converting-command filein fileout')
```

I suggest you go with PythonMagic as Creshal said. It is provided by ImageMagic and thus must be one of the best port available for python.